# TikZ: xsetlength and smaller lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

I am trying to create a custom environment `warning` which has a warning sign on the top left and a frame around it. For a reason I do not understand, though, the left line drawn to the west is much smaller than the one that `cycle` creates.

[image: lines smalller]

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[leqno,hyperref={pdfpagemode=FullScreen},aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\newenvironment{warning}{%
\tcolorbox[enhanced,title=\faicon{warning},colback=white,
boxrule=0mm,coltitle=red,
attach boxed title to top left=
{yshift=-0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=2mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},%
boxed title style={empty,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt, leftrule=-0.5em, toprule=-2pt}, 
frame code={
\draw[red,rounded corners=2pt,line width=0.8pt]  let \p1=($(title.north)-(frame.north)$) in
(title.north west) -- (title.north) -- ++ (\y1+0.2pt,-\y1+0.2pt) -|
([xshift=0.2pt, yshift=-0.4pt,rounded corners=0pt]frame.south east) -|
([xshift=-0.4pt, yshift=0.2pt,rounded corners=0pt]frame.west) -- cycle
;}]}
{\endtcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{warning}
    \lipsum[2]
  \end{warning}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It must have something to do with the `tikz` drawing and especially with the `x-shift` commands, but I'm new to it and cannot see the error. Here is a full picture:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've only changed your `boxrule=0` in main tcolorbox to `boxrule=0.8pt`.

And as an independent change I've used a `newtcolorbox` instead of a `newenvironment`.

i'm not sure about why boxrule changes the line width, but I suspect that
boxrules are not lines but differences between a backgorund box and a text box. This way with a `boxrule=0pt`, there is not enough space for the line.

```
\documentclass[leqno,hyperref={pdfpagemode=FullScreen},aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\newtcolorbox{warning}{
enhanced,title=\faicon{warning},colback=white,
boxrule=0.8pt,coltitle=red,
attach boxed title to top left=
{yshift=-0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=2mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},%
boxed title style={empty,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt, leftrule=-0.5em, toprule=-2pt}, 
frame code={
\draw[red,rounded corners=2pt,line width=0.8pt]  let \p1=($(title.north)-(frame.north)$) in
(title.north west) -- (title.north) -- ++ (\y1+0.2pt,-\y1+0.2pt) -|
([xshift=0.2pt, yshift=-0.4pt,rounded corners=0pt]frame.south east) -|
([xshift=-0.4pt, yshift=0.2pt,rounded corners=0pt]frame.west) -- cycle
;}}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{warning}
    \lipsum[2]
  \end{warning}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for! Could you explain why you chose a value of 0.8? And do you know why `newtcolorbox` is not listed in the tcolorbox manual anymore? I chose the new environment because it is done so in the manual, too. What are the perks of using `newtcolorbox`? In any case, your answer is very much appreciated!

Comment: @VitusSchäfftlein I selected 0.8 because it was the value that you selected in `frame code` (`draw` options). About `newtcolorbox`, I can see the command in page 15 on my documentation (v5.0.2).

Comment: Makes sense about the `draw` option! Concerning `newtcolorbox`, I messed up; took the first google result which was from 2012. I checked out the newest version from CTAN and its there. Thank you!